# HP-au123cl laptop is buzzing when charger is plugged in

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a 4 y.o. HP-au123cl laptop running Windows 10 that started making a buzzing noise a couple of days ago when power adapter gets plugged in. If I unplug the adaptor and plug back in, noise stops. The battery indicator in the taskbar stays still in the last few days and says the same thing and does not change "36% available (plugged in)". Adaptor is not hot, cables don't have any damages, adaptor's plug is not loose. Everything seems to be normal besides the noise. Unfortunately, I don't have any spare adaptor or battery to troubleshoot the issue. Is this a battery or adaptor issue? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Likely a battery issue. If it's the original one,i.e., a 4 years old battery it's as good as dead.

Comment: A good battery on a good machine with a Threshold Manager will easily go 4 years or more.  Also be alert to a buzzing sound inside could be an indication of overload if the internal circuit as failed in some way.

Comment: It could be a bad dc jack on the laptop, is it a tight fit when you plug it in?

Answer (score 0):

Most of my laptops have batteries 5 years old or more. Given light use and with a partial charge, Li-ion batteries last *far* longer. However, if the battery is frequently discharged deeply (below 20%), it may die far sooner. Furthermore, it appears there has been a *recall on [the HP Pavilion 15-au123cl battery](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Recall-battery-on-the-HP-Pavilion-15/td-p/5965839)*.

The cause of the issue could be either the battery or charger. One way to test if the battery is at fault is to fully shut down, remove the battery, and operate from the power supply *alone*. On some laptops, the battery is easily removable, but [it takes some effort to access that in the HP Pavilion 15-au123cl](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/HP+Pavilion+15-au123cl+Battery+Replacement/100064). If you plan on purchasing a third-party battery ([available for US$50 or less](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07GRYMJ4W)), you might open the case and unplug the battery to test if that's the cause, but if you hope for replacement under warranty, don't open the case, but look for a similar charger to test it.